# Can't find solution for - Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am trying to implement a logic where use should be returned to login page in case of direct link to some products in NopCommerce site.

**I have implemented redirect code here:**

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName != "Home" && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName != "Customer" &&
                filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "Index" && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "Login")
            {
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["AgeAuth"] == null)
                {
                    var HomeUrl = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext).RouteUrl("AgeAuthPage") +"?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(HomeUrl);
                }
            }
}
```

**Home page controller code:**

```
public ActionResult AgeAuth()
        {
            if (_httpContext.Session == null || _httpContext.Session["AgeAuth"] == null)
            {
                var model = new LoginModel();
                model.UsernamesEnabled = true;

                return View(model);
                //return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AgeAuth(FormCollection frm, string returnUrl)
        {
            DateTime _birthdate = new DateTime(int.Parse(frm["birthyear"].ToString()), int.Parse(frm["birthmonth"].ToString()), int.Parse(frm["birthday"].ToString()));
            DateTime _now = DateTime.Now;
            int age = _now.Year - _birthdate.Year;

            if (_now.Month < _birthdate.Month || (_now.Month == _birthdate.Month && _now.Day < _birthdate.Day))
                age--;

            if (age > 21)
            {
                _httpContext.Session["AgeAuth"] = "Valid";
                _httpContext.Session.Timeout = 720;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

I know one of the partial view is causing some issue, but I am not really sure where look for it in below stack trace. I am new to NopCommerce and MVC.

Can I get a pointer to start at?

**Here is the stack trace:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions. 
at System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)  
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9() 
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() 
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func) 
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) 
at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) 
at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValues) 
at Nop.Web.Framework.HtmlExtensions.Widget(HtmlHelper helper, String widgetZone, Object additionalData) 
at ASP._Page_Themes_Lavella_Views_Shared__ProductBox_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\test-eCommerce\Themes\Lavella\Views\Shared\_ProductBox.cshtml:line 91 
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) 
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) 
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model) 
at ASP._Page_Views_PromotionPage_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\test-eCommerce\Views\PromotionPage\Index.cshtml:line 24 
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() 
at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() 
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) 
at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) 
at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you debug your code? Because there are many redirection code is there in above code. it's little confusing to predict which is giving issue. But by seeing error I can tell you that somewhere you have redirected on the Child Action, which is not possible. So best suggestion is to debug code line by line and find out the issue. Hope this helps.